# How to write a conditional in regex

Tags: regex

I have the follow line of regex (javascript)

```
/^[a-z0-9_.\-]+@(yahoo|gmail|excite})\.com$/
```

However, I am unsure of how to make this include subdomains (IF one is present).

So this expression should match uk.yahoo.com and yahoo.com email address as well... How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want *just* the subdomain `uk.yahoo.com`:

`/^[a-z0-9_.\-]+@((?:uk\.)?yahoo|gmail|excite)\.com$/`

The addition of `(?:uk\.)?` specifies a optional noncapturing group that matches either 0 or 1 occurrence of the pattern "`uk.`".

However, using regexes to validate email addresses is an [awful idea](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt). [RFC2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) is a **very** complex standard. It's much better to blindly send an email to whatever minimally-validated address the user enters, fail early, and give the user a chance to correct the mistake.

Comment: Well not that specific, but any subdomain. .uk was only an example - this is only to make some CSS changes with jQuery. I have server-side validation in place as well .

Comment: You can change the `uk\.` to `\S+\.`, then. That'll capture 1 or more non-whitespace characters, followed by the `\.`.

Comment: Like this? `/^[a-z0-9_.\-]+@((?:\S+\.)?yahoo|gmail|excite)\.com$/` - that one isn't working for me. I'm testing using regexpal.com

Comment: Here, try this: `/^[a-z0-9_.\-]+@((?:\S+\.)?(?:yahoo|gmail|excite))\.com$/`. That could probably be made more efficient, but it'll work in a pinch.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but that one isn't working either. I'm using regexpal.com to test.